# How generic Message<T> works?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to understand how `Message<T>` works while using with kafka message processor. I'm new in spring framework.

For example, I've below method in `@Service` class (dont bother about code error). This method is processing the messages which are being pushed in below method by kafka consumer at run time.

```
@kafkaListener(id="id", topics="$consumer.topic", groupId = "$group-id", autoStartUp = "false"
public void myKafkaConsumerMessages(Message<BusinessEvents> message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.Received_Partition_Id) Integer id, @Header(KafkaHeaders.Offset) Integer offset, Acknowledgement ack) {

    BusinessEvents bi = message.getPayload();

}
```

I dont have access to `BusinessEvents` class, so cant see what's there. So want to know, If my code is like above then `BusinessEvents` must have implemented `Message` interface ?

If answer is no, then where `Message<T>` coming into flow and able to produce message of `BusinessEvents` by just using `getPayload()` ?

I'm curious to know how `Message<T>` playing its part and able to produce `BusinessEvents` type ? To be able to produce `BusinessEvents` type, message coming from kafka has to be of `BusinessEvents` type ?

I hope my question is clear to all, if not please let me know I'll try to explain more.

Comment: Do you understand generics?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes sir I do

Comment: I don't know Kafka at all, but I would imagine that BusinessEvents gets serialized at one end and deserialized at the other.  If you understand generics, the rest should be apparent; you can think of Message<T> as a container for a message of any type T.

Comment: Not knowing the definition of `Message`, it's hard to know for sure, but a `Message<BusinessEvents>` object is likely an object representing a message that **contains** a BusinessEvents object.  Given a `Message<BusinessEvents>` object, I'd expect that you could obtain a `BusinessEvents` object from it (with `getPayload()` maybe?).  Generics have nothing to do with inheritance,  so `BusinessEvents` doesn't need to implement `Message` or anything else. If the definition of `Message` is truly just `Message<T>`, then it will take any type.

Comment: This code isn't producing anything. You've defined a listener/consumer, which is deserializing the BusinessEvents class, which you **do** have access to, otherwise, this code wouldn't compile

Comment: @TrinTrin Saying "then BusinessEvents must have implemented Message interface" is not what `Message<BusinessEvents>` mean.  You might want to study generics a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The `Message` object is a container object for Spring Messaging. It's not required as you can define a `@KafkaListener` method with a `K key, V value` parameter instead, or even just the value type. In general, I'd say that there isn't a strong use case for using the `Message` object if you're not accessing Kafka record headers, not interacting with other spring-messaging dependencies, and only care about the record value (payload).

If you do use a `Message`, then you need to define a [`MessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion) which wraps the Kafka serialization processes.

Answer (score -1):

I think the comments are clear enough, but sometimes since seeing code can help you understand it better, so here's a naive implementation of Message:

```
public class Message<T> {
    
    private final T payload;
    
    public Message(final T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    
    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a custom class, it comes from Spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#reply-message

Comment: I know. I'm just trying to show him how a container class would look like using generics. Obviously this is not the real implementation.

Comment: Sure, but I think a better answer would explain how Spring actually uses the Message class overall (since it's not required) than briefly explaining how generics work

Comment: I think that's not what he's asking, maybe he can make the question more clear.

Comment: _trying to understand **how Message<T> works** while using with kafka message processor. I'm new in spring framework_.... _curious to know **how Message<T> playing its part**_